# Leave evil's insert state with Control + c

Tags: key-bindings, evil, doom

I would like to be able to leave the insert state (I think that's what it's called in emacs?) using the Ctrl+c combination I know from vim. I'm using doom-emacs in case that's important, and I'm completely new to emacs.

Comment: Let me suggest you find a different keybinding to exit insert state (or just use esc). Emacs uses the C-c prefix for countless keybindings, and if you override it, you'll clobber a lot of functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ex-vimmer also. As Dan pointed out in the comment of OP, binding to `C-c` is too devastating in emacs. What I do is instead binding to `C-c C-c` so I can hit `C-c` like a crazy person to get back to normal. (Just like hitting `C-s` 10 times is the proper way to save MS Word documents, I do this a lot: `C-c C-c C-c ... C-c C-g C-g ... C-g` to make sure I'm in normal state)

```lisp
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'evil-normal-state)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'evil-normal-state)
```

Note, this has a downside though (not very serious or often encounterd), is that you would override some useful `C-c C-c` bindings from famous packages, like `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` in org-mode, as well as several cases for magit. It's not serious in the sense that I use Spacemacs which also binds these common `C-c C-c` cases to `, ,` for `evil-normal-state`, so I'm not really missing anything important. In your case you are using doom-emacs, which is somewhat influenced by Spacemacs, it might also have provided a nice keybinding alternative already. If not, nothing can stop you from rebinding some `C-c C-c` cases yourself.